# Some help with regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to come up with cheeky regexp myself, but no luck so far. I hope one of you can make my day!

Data:

```
This_is.S0meNam3_.var01.tar
This_is.S0meNam3_.var1.tar.gz
This_is.S0meNam3_.tar.gz
```

After parsing all the given exmaples I an looking forward to have at leat to groups

```
Group1 -> Group2  
This_is.S0meNam3_ -> .tar  
This_is.S0meNam3_ -> .tar.gz  
This_is.S0meNam3_ -> .tar.gz
```

I hope it all makes sense.

Thanks you.

Comment: What pattern does the `This_is-S0meNam3` part follow?  Is it only letters and numbers?

Comment: It does not make a whole lot of sense. What is the criteria? Are you only looking for `.tar.gz` and `.tar`? Or are there other file extensions you need to be able to handle aswell?

Comment: What I am trying to do is ...  get rid of any file extension and then if string contains .varXX it should be removed as well.

Comment: justing: I would say pretty much everyting ... no limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^(.*?)(?:\.var\d+)?((?:\.tar)?(?:\.gz)?|(?:\.(?:zip|rar)))$
```

This assumes that the only possible endings are `.zip`, `.rar`, `.tar`, `.gz` and `.tar.gz`, and that the things you want removed all are of the form `.var<n>` for some number `<n>`.

Getting it to accept any extension isn't really possible without narrowing it down further, as `This_is.S0meNam3_.tar.gz` could be split into filename and extension in all of the following ways:

```
This_is                   -    S0meNam3_.tar.gz
This_is.S0meNam3_         -    tar.gz
This_is.S0meNam3_.tar     -    gz
```

Comment: nearly there... can we add another case:

This_is.S0meNam3_.zip
This_is.S0meNam3_.var1.rar

Comment: +1 in particular for the observation that you need a list of known extensions to remove if there is a . in the filename somewhere. Also a nice regular expression which reminded me of the existence of non-cpaturing groups. :)